# What is the best way to connect my React admin frontend to my Nodejs/Express server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I want to connect my React application to my NodeJs/Express backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the question is about HTTP requests in JavaScript with React and NodeJs, you have many ways to do that, either you choose [Ajax](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(informatique)) or [jQuery Methods](https://jquery.com/) or [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or and it's the best way for me is to use [Fetch methode](http://javascript.info/fetch)